# L^p space and inverse

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $A: ℓ^\infty \rightarrow ℓ^\infty$ be defined as $A(x_k)=x_k/k$.

First I need to show that A is injective. I think this follows from $A(x_k)=A(y_k) \Rightarrow x_k/k=y_k/k \Rightarrow x_k=y_k$?

Next I need to show that A is continuous. If we take two sequences $x_k,y_k$ in $ℓ^\infty$ we see that if $x_k \rightarrow x$ then $A(x_k) = x_k/k \rightarrow x/k = A(x)$?

I struggle to show the the next thing which is why A is not surjective. Also I need to give a formula for $A^{-1}:A(ℓ^\infty) \rightarrow ℓ^\infty$ and prove that $A^{-1}$ is not continous. How could I achieve this? Also what can I say about $A(ℓ^\infty)$ and how does this compare to the theorem of continuous inverses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of injectivity is fine.

$A$ is linear and $\|A(x_k)| \leq \|(x_k)\|$ since $\frac  1 k \leq 1$ for all $k$. So $A$ is a bounded operator , hence continuous.

$A$ is not surjective because $(1,1,...) \in \ell^{\infty}$  and we cannot have $(x_k) \in \ell^{\infty}$ with $\frac {x_k} k=1$ for all $k$. [We would have $x_k=k$ so $(x_k)$ won't be bounded].

$A^{-1}(y_k)=(ky_k)$ defined on sequence $(y_k)$ for which $(ky_k)$ is bounded.

$A^{-1}$ is not bounded because $(\frac  1 n, \frac  1 n,...) \to 0$ but $\|A^{-1}(\frac  1 n, \frac  1 n,...)\|\geq n\frac  1 n=1$. [The norm of a sequence  $(a_k)$ in $\ell^{\infty}$ is at least $|a_n|$ (for any $n$). I am taking the $n-$th coefficient in $A^{-1}(\frac  1 n, \frac  1 n,...)$].